# Evaluating an integral using the Jacobian help!

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

For this question I have managed to sketch the region however I don't understand how to solve this sort of a problem where we have two regions? 
Also when we use the change of variable formula with the Jacobian is that for **one** region only?

Here we have two regions. one where x>0 and one where x<0 but that's all that I have been able to understand from this question and would be grateful if someone could provide some explanation with how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you sketched the regions in the $ \ xy-$ plane over which we wish to integrate, you likely found something that looks like this:

[image]

I have marked the intersection points between the pairs of semi-circles and pairs of parabolas; I haven't bothered to give the coordinates of those points, since we won't be using them anywhere.  Notice the interesting feature that the "upper" parabola intersects the "lower" semi-circle at *only one* point.

Now, we are given a specific variable substitution to use:  $ \ u \ = \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ , \ v \ = \ y \ - \ x^2 \ $ .  This has the effect of turning the pairs of curves into

$$ y \ = \ \sqrt{1 \ - \ x^2}  \ \ \rightarrow \ \ u \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ \ y \ = \ \sqrt{4 \ - \ x^2}  \ \ \rightarrow \ \ u \ = \ 4 \ \ ; $$

$$ y \ = \ x^2  \ \ \rightarrow \ \ v \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ y \ = \ 1 \ + \ x^2  \ \ \rightarrow \ \ v \ = \ 1 \ \ . $$

We now have two pairs of parallel lines forming a *single* rectangle with just four intersection points:

[image]

Our original two regions now "overlap" onto one rectangle.  If we work out what becomes of the intersection points, we find that the former "right-hand" region is "mapped" onto the rectangle with the "circulation" of the intersections $ \ A'B'C'D' \ $ being counter-clockwise ("positive" orientation).  However, the former "left-hand" region is mapped onto the *same* rectangle, but with the path through intersections $ \ D'E'F'G' \ $ being *clockwise* ("negative" orientation).

This may be dropping us a hint about what the value of the integral is.  If we were calculating an integral of some function of a single variable in one direction over a particular interval, and added it to an integral of the same function over the same interval in the *opposite* direction, what would happen?

$$ \ \ $$

The Jacobian determinant of the transformation is given by

$$ \mathfrak{J} \ = \ \frac{1}{\left| \begin{array}{cc}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{array}\right|} \ = \ \frac{1}{\left| \begin{array}{cc} 2x&2y\\-2x&1\end{array}\right|} \ = \ \frac{1}{2x \ (1+2y)} \ \ . $$

Notice that the Jacobian becomes undefined for $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ , that is, just at the point $ \  D \ $ .  It does apply to both regions, but has opposite signs on either side of the $ \ y-$ axis. (It also provides a valuable simplification in transforming the integral you are asked to compute.)